# AdventureWorks SQL conflicting results issue

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, adventureworks

I'm working with the AdventureWorks example DB - we're running SQL Server 2008R2, so I assume that's the edition of AdventureWorks (I have read-only access). I'm trying to get a list of sales managers so that I can then determine a couple employee/manager relationships.
I'm getting two sets of three differently named people, with the same job title, with their CurrentFlag set to 1 (active) with slightly different queries. I do notice that one result group has the same contactID and employeeID, but I'm not sure what this may indicate.

So the question is: Why am I getting completely different results with these two queires? I would think I'd get six results for each - the queries are matching employee table Titles.

- SQL Query 1:

  ```
  select 
     c.FirstName, 
     c.LastName, 
     c.ContactID, 
     e.EmployeeID, 
     e.Title, 
     c.Title, 
     e.CurrentFlag
  from Person.Contact c 
  inner join HumanResources.Employee e
     on c.ContactID = e.ContactID
  where 
     e.Title like '%Sales Manager%'
  ```
- SQL Query 2:

  ```
  SELECT 
     e.EmployeeID, 
     (c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName) as 'First Name and Last Name', 
     e.Title
  FROM HumanResources.Employee e 
  INNER JOIN Person.Contact c
      ON e.EmployeeID = c.ContactID
  Where 
      e.Title LIKE '%Manager%'
      AND
      e.Title LIKE '%Sales%'
  ORDER BY e.EmployeeID;
  ```

UPDATE: These are my results:

- SQL Query 1:

  ```
  -------  -------  ----  ---  ----------------------------  ----  --
  Stephen  Jiang    1011  268  North American Sales Manager  NULL  1
  Amy      Alberts  1013  284  European Sales Manager        NULL  1
  Syed     Abbas    1012  288  Pacific Sales Manager         Mr.   1
  ```
- SQL Query 2:

  ```
  ---  ---  -----------  ----------------------------  ---  --
  268  268  Gary Drury   North American Sales Manager  Mr.  1
  284  284  John Emory   European Sales Manager        Mr.  1
  288  288  Julie Estes  Pacific Sales Manager         Ms.  1
  ```

Comment: The 2 queries seem identical ...

Comment: Yea, sorry I didn't realize I had copied one locally and the other was on an RDC... updated.

Comment: It would help if you added the definitions of the 2 tables (so we see the FKs) but it's obvious why you are getting different results. The `ON` clauses are different.

Comment: All your employees have an `EmployeeID` and a `ContactID` and the 2 queries are using each one of these different columns for the join. Different columns, different meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only diffrents i can see is this:

```
where 
   e.Title like '%Sales Manager%'
```

And this:

```
Where 
 e.Title LIKE '%Manager%'
    AND
  e.Title LIKE '%Sales%'
```

The first query says that bring me all titles that has `'%Sales Manager%'` you can have for ex this output:

```
Account Sales Manager
some Sales Manager
Sales Manager something else
```

The second question says bring me all the titles that has `'%Manager%`' and `'%Sales%'` so you can for ex have:

```
Sales Account Manager
some Sales some Manager some 
Sales Manager some else thing
Manager Sales
```

And this join can not be corrent

```
INNER JOIN Person.Contact c
    ON e.EmployeeID = c.ContactID
```

Don't you mean:

```
INNER JOIN Person.Contact c
        ON e.ContactID= c.ContactID
```

Comment: Thanks! I see now that I was miss-reading my FK relationship, and now I'm getting correct results off the contactID. I suppose I was managing to mash the tables together before, but of course then getting irregular results.

Answer (score 1):

The first query will match the rows where substring "Sales Manager" is present. But second one can match rows like "Managers of Sales Dep" as well. I mean the second doesn't care about positions of the words in the srting.

I believe that the results of first query is a subset of the results of second one.

**UPDATE**
You use different columns in JOIN clause, so it's normal that you got different results.